# java regex hyphen within string multiple times

Tags: java, regex, match

I have a Java program that should match a string if it contains a hyphen for more than 5 times in it:

```
hello-hi-contains-more-than-five-hyphen
```

The words can contain any regular characters.

The regex should not match on this example:

```
hi-hello-233-here-example
```

I tried to write a regex like this:

```
.*-{6,}.*
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: I think it will be a lot more easier and convenient if you use [`String.split('-')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) and then check if the length is more than 6 or not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it was a part of my regex that I needed

Comment: An alternative that doesn’t use a regular expression: `booleam matches = str.codePoints().filter(c -> c == '-').count() > 5;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Regex, then you could try the following:

```
^(.*?-){6,}.*$
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/Sl1xli/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
"...".matches("(?s)([^-]*-){6}.*")
```

- `(?s)` dot-all, `.` will also match line separators like `\r` and `n`.
- group `( )`, 6 times `{6}`, any char `.` 0 or more times `*`
- group with char set `[]` *not* `^` containing `-`, 0 or more times `*`, followed by `-`

For `matches` the regex must cover the entire string, so `^` (start) and `$` (end) are already implied. (Hence the need for `.*`)

Answer (score 0):

No need for *expensive* regex here, a simple `split` and  `length` will do it, i.e.:

```
String subjectString = "hello-hi-contains-more-than-five-hyphen";
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("-");
if(splitArray.length > 5){
    System.out.println(subjectString);
}
```

---

[Java Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QtS)